# Unexpected qualifier Id before const

Tags: c++, class, constructor, constants, copy-constructor

In my `.h` I have my class with a struct:

```
class BST
{
public:
    struct BinaryNode
    {
        //variables     
        BinaryNode& operator=(const BinaryNode node) ;

        BinaryNode(SequenceMap i);
        ~BinaryNode();

        BinaryNode(const BinaryNode &otherNode);

    };
};
```

---

In my `.cpp` I implement my copy constructor:

```
BST::BinaryNode(const BST::BinaryNode &otherNode)
{
    item = otherNode.item;  
    if(otherNode.left != nullptr)
        left = otherNode.left;
    else
        left = nullptr;
    if(otherNode.right != nullptr)
        right = otherNode.right;
    else
        right = nullptr;
}
```

When it compiles, on `BST::BinaryNode(const BST::BinaryNode &otherNode)` I have an unexpected qualifier id before const.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The copy constructor should be written as the following for definition:

```
BST::BinaryNode::BinaryNode(const BST::BinaryNode &otherNode)
             //^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    //...
}
```

The `BST::BinaryNode` at the left is class name; the `BinaryNode` at the right is function name.